# 2004 Toyota Corolla breaker breaks when I use a power outlet

Tags: electrical, corolla, power-outlet

I have an 04 Corolla.  If I plug anything into either of the 2 power outlets it destroys a breaker.  I thought about replacing the power outlet, but since it happens to both outlets I think there's something else wrong.

How can I troubleshoot and fix this?

**UPDATE**
I found the wiring [diagram](http://www.scribd.com/doc/40916345/Manual-Toyota-Corolla-2004-Wiring-Manual#outer_page_105) for the cigarette lighter.  I think the issue is at ground point IE (listed in diagram).  I'm also having issues with the clock display which goes in and out.  The clock appears to share the same junction point.

[image]

Comment: What size fuse are you installing What is the rated current draw of the device you are plugging in? Have you plugged in any other devices to rule out it being the device itself that is defective?

Comment: 15A fuse.  Device is a magellon GPS.  Also tried phone charger.

Comment: Basically, when you add anything on this circuit you will drain more than 15A overall. You have to find which system/accessories are draining too much amps. Do you have an aftermarket radio/accessories that could have been hard wired into the cigarette lighter circuit?

Comment: @GabrielMongeon - The car is all stock.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to see the grounding points by crawling under the dash.  The grounds looked visually good, the screws are tight.  So, I tried replacing the 12V power outlet with a new aftermarket outlet.  The issue is gone.

Strange that the one bad outlet actually caused both outlets to blow fuses when power was drawn.